# configuring proxy_pass multiple params with ngnix

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I need to set proxy_pass for the below url pattern.

```
location  ~ ^/hosts/bu/(.*)/app/(.*)$ {
  proxy_pass   http://appserver.cnma.com:3000/hosts/bu/$1/app/$2;
}
```

When I try with the URL it does not pass the second parameter correctly. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Any reason against simple `location /hosts/bu/ { proxy_pass   http://appserver.cnma.com:3000 }` ?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the URL you are trying to call?

Comment: Thanks @Alexey. Let me try this solution and get back to you with the result.

Answer (score 1):

you can use named capture in nginx while using regular expressions

```
location  ~ ^/hosts/bu/(.*)/app/(.*)$ {
  proxy_pass   http://appserver.cnma.com:3000/hosts/bu/$1/app/$2;
}
```

You can modify block to below like this

```
location  ~ ^/hosts/bu/(?<loc1>.+)/app/(?<loc2>.+)$ {
  proxy_pass   http://appserver.cnma.com:3000/hosts/bu/$1/app/$loc2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Orig [docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) say:

If proxy_pass is specified without a URI, the request URI is passed to the server in the same form as sent by a client when the original request is processed, or the full normalized request URI is passed when processing the changed URI:

```
location /some/path/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
}
```

So there is enough:

```
proxy_pass http://appserver.cnma.com:3000$request_uri;
```

Comment: If the url parameters are encoded in the browser will the proxy_pass redirect with the encoding on? I am seeing that the encoding is removed when using the prosy_pass. Please explain.

Comment: It seems you want to keep orig URI as is, try to append **$request_uri**, I updated the answer above